# Can one still use runtime DOM manipulation in a Nuxt generated site?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt/Vue project which I'm using to pre-render a single page website (not SPA, but static universal mode) via the generate command. All the static html is being rendered correctly but I would like to do a call to the Google Sheets API at *runtime* and update the DOM with values I receive. Does any of Vue's reactivity remain after a nuxt generate? Or would I have to go the vanilla javascript Nuxt plugin route for DOM manipulation?

The system into which we're placing this code is served by Adobe Experience Manager, so Nuxt SSR is unfortunately out of the question.

Comment: EDIT: Some people seem to do a workaround by loading in the VueJS script from a CDN at runtime and actually creating a new Vue() for the element I want to be reactive. This seems logical, but is it best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works for me. <strike>Loading in Vue from the CDN via the header object of nuxt.config:</strike>

```
script: [
  {src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js'}
],
```

<strike>will cause Vue to be loaded at runtime. Remember to load the full bundle with the compiler as we're doing runtime templating.</strike> Now create a plugin for client only (set mode to 'client' OR name your file my-script.client.js) and place it inside the ~/plugins directory:

```
plugins: [
  {src: '~/plugins/my-script', mode: 'client' }
],
```

Inside my-script.js you can create a new Vue() which will mount a *.vue SFC:

```
import Vue from 'vue'; // Not sure if this is strictly required
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue';

new Vue({
  render: h => h(MyComponent)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Obviously for this to work you need a div with an id of #app inside the pre-rendered code.

Comment: Are you sure you need to include Vue from CDN ? You know, if `MyComponent.vue` is included in the JS bundle, Vue itself is probably too....

Comment: Not 100% sure, no. I'll give it a bash without it and feed back.

Comment: OK so you're absolutely right - it does NOT require loading in Vue at runtime from the CDN. Will edit my answer.